# How do I determine the mysql bin path from phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, path, phpmyadmin

I need the path to the mysql executable file (bin?), usually /usr/bin/mysql I think, but in my case it's not.

To add to the challenge, I need to find it from phpmyadmin, as I'm using a shared host.

So far, I tried "select @@datadir', which gives me var/lib/mysql, but I think that may be something different altogether than what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've never needed to know this for any project. Are you sure you're asking the right question?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. It's for a WP pluging called "SitePush", it lets you set up staging environments and transfer files to and from them, presumably using mysql. Anyway, it asks for the path to rsync, mysql, and mysqldump. Thanks!